# Making a List<string> from Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I was wondering if it were possible to make a list from the dictionary values where the key is a specified value?

The dictionary would like this:

Sidcup - DPC1
Sidcup - DPC2
Blackheath - DPC3
Blackheath - DPC4
Bexleyheath - DPC5

In fact, I'm not entirely implementing a Dictionary as above is a good idea. Here is its implementation:

```
DataSet ds = EngineBllUtility.GetDPCsForImportFile(connectionString, fileID);
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dtDPCs = EngineBllUtility.GetDPCsForImportFile(connectionString, fileID).Tables[0];
    Dictionary<string, string> preliminaryList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (dtDPCs.Columns.Contains("DPCNumber") && dtDPCs.Columns.Contains("BranchName"))
       foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtDPCs.Rows)
       {
            preliminaryList.Add(dataRow["BranchName"].ToString(), dataRow["DPCNumber"].ToString());
       }
```

I have the following code: (Excuse the last line, its just so you have an idea of what I'm trying to do).

```
foreach (string branch in branchNames)
{
    string subfolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(saveLocation, branch);
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subfolder);

    List<string> certificateList = new List<string>();

    certificateList.Add(DPCNumber in preliminaryList where Key = branch);
}
```

In the above the branch is the key from the Dictionary. I need to iterate through because it needs to create a new folder and then do something with the certificateList I am creating.

Comment: You will have only one value per key in your dictionary , why you want to make a list from it ?

Comment: You are initializing `certificateList` on every iteration of the loop, and within a block. It can't be used outside the loop. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Oded Yes, this is desired, if you read to the end of the question you would see that

Comment: Not being able to use the variable outside of the loop doesn't automatically follow from that sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
private static void TestZip()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> stringstringdic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        stringstringdic.Add("1", "One");
        stringstringdic.Add("2", "Two");
        stringstringdic.Add("3", "Three");
        stringstringdic.Add("4", "Four");
        stringstringdic = stringstringdic.Where(pair => pair.Key != "1")
                                         .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
        List<string> stringlist = stringstringdic.Keys.Concat(stringstringdic.Values).ToList();
        foreach (string str in stringlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

//Output:    
//2
//3
//4
//Two
//Three
//Four
```

Of course, you'll have to change the Where clause to reflect your real need.
If I understood you right, it's like `.Where(pair => pair.Key == branch)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add the value based on a key to a separate List?

```
certificateList.Add(preliminaryList[branch])
```

This is simplified as I really need to see the declaration of preliminaryList to know how `DPCNumber` fits into all of it. Could it be...

```
certificateList.Add(preliminaryList[branch].ToString())
```

Answer (score -1):

To simply create a list of keys you can do the following.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("key1", "value1");
dictionary.Add("key2", "value2");
dictionary.Add("key3", "value3");
dictionary.Add("key4", "value4");
dictionary.Add("key5", "value5");

var list = dictionary.Keys.ToList();
```

This should give you a list with values "key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5".

You can put a where clause in to filter out certain keys. The following gives all keys which contain a "2" (random example), resulting in just "key2".

```
var filteredList = dictionary.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains("2")).ToList();
```

Edit: 
To get a value given a specific key.

```
string value = dictionary["key1"];
```

Note, the key is a dictionary must be unique, so for a given key you will only ever get a single value back and not a list of values.

Comment: I want to generate a list of `values` where the `key` is a specified string

Comment: Ah ok, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) "Every key in a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> must be unique according to the dictionary's equality comparer" so you will only ever get one value for a given key. I'll update my answer to reflect this change to the question.